# Android MPAndroidChart chart height

Tags: android, height, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart library to plot charts but I can't get the height right. No matter what value I put it remains a very compressed and not valid chart height.

Would you be able to help out?

Chart now:
[image]

This is my .xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="it.bitrack.fabio.bitrack.AssetView"
    android:id="@+id/assetView_relative_layout"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/pressureLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Pressure"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:padding="10dp" />

                <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                    android:id="@+id/pressureLineChart"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:padding="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/pressureSelectedTextView"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Nothing selected"
                    android:padding="10dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my chart plotting:

```
final ArrayList<Entry> lineEntries = new ArrayList<>();


            for (Asset a: assetList) {

                lineEntries.add(new Entry((epoch.getEpoch(a.datetime) - EPOCH_OFFSET), a.pressure));

                Log.i("BiTrack(adding)", epoch.getEpoch(a.datetime) + " " + a.datetime);

            }

            //line chart data
            LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(lineEntries, "Pressure");
            lineDataSet.setValueTextSize(CHART_VALUE_TEXT_SIZE);

            ArrayList<ILineDataSet> lineDataSets = new ArrayList<>();
            lineDataSets.add(lineDataSet);

            LineData lineData = new LineData(lineDataSets);
            pressureLineChartLayout.setData(lineData);

            Description d = new Description();
            d.setText(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

            pressureLineChartLayout.setDescription(d);
            pressureLineChartLayout.setMinimumHeight(250);
            pressureLineChartLayout.setExtraBottomOffset(50f);

            XAxis xAxis = pressureLineChartLayout.getXAxis();
            xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(45f);
            xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

            xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {

                @Override
                public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {

                    return epoch.getDatetimeNoYear(((long) value) + EPOCH_OFFSET);

                }
            });

            pressureLineChartLayout.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onValueSelected(Entry entry, Highlight highlight) {
                    //display msg when value selected
                    if (entry == null)
                        return;
//                Toast.makeText(context, epoch.getDatetime((int) entry.getX()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    pressureSelectedTextView.setText("Date: " + epoch.getDatetime(((long) entry.getX()) + EPOCH_OFFSET) + ", Pressure: " + entry.getY() + " mbar");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected() {
                    pressureSelectedTextView.setText("Nothing selected");
                }
            });

            pressureLineChartLayout.notifyDataSetChanged();
            pressureLineChartLayout.invalidate();

            pressureLinearLayout.setVisibility(getView().VISIBLE);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make it work the way I wanted by removing the `pressureLineChartLayout.setMinimumHeight` property and setting the `pressureLineChartLayout.setExtraBottomOffset` to `-50` instead of `50`.

Those two things made the magic - don't ask me why.

Comment: where i have to remove these lines, I'm facing the same problem